# Downloading a file from Firebase Storage changes its name

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

Whenever I download a file from the Firebase Storage to an Android device, the name of the file changes i.e. from filename.pdf to e.g. filename-13557732.pdf

Is there any way to prevent that change? Why does this happen?

```
File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory 
    (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).getAbsolutePath());

final File localFile = File.createTempFile(filename,".pdf", directory);
mStorageReference.child(filename).getFile(localFile)
```

Also, by any chance, is there a way to download a file with URL (which I already have) and not name?

Comment: How do you download? Is it part of an application you develop, or you use your device as normal user and trigger the system download manager?

Comment: It is a part of an application I developed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Q: How to change default name in createTempFile?

The answer: 
    You can't.

If you could you would invalidate the guarantees of createTempFile which, according to the javadoc, are:

The file denoted by the returned abstract pathname did not exist before this method was invoked, and
Neither this method nor any of its variants will return the same abstract pathname again in the current invocation of the virtual machine.
If you care about the filename maybe createTempFile() is not the appropriate way to create the file.

You can find out what the system temp file directory is and create your own file there, but you will have to manage the possibility of filename collisions yourself.

An alternative strategy to using createTempFile depends on what you are using the file for and why you care what it's named, which you don't state.

Q: Is there a way to Download this using URL.

The answer: Yes.

There are different ways to do this. Check [This Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)

So to simply put it.

```
private FirebaseStorage storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();



storageRef.child("users/me/profile.png").getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
        // Got the download URL for 'users/me/profile.png'
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
});
```

You can Use, Picasso or Glide. Or simply create your own method on handing the URL. It may say URI but it is really URL.